# How to do test-driven development?

Tags: tdd, ocaml

I think everything is in the title but I am looking specifically for:

- What is the "standard" unit test framework in OCaml?
- How do I integrate executing tests in the build?
- How to automatically execute tests upon every file change?

As a bonus, I would be interested in test coverage tooling...

Comment: There is no adherence to ocaml ; Jenkins provide the framework to do so. Regarding tst coverage for ocaml : there is Bisect ( but based on camlp4).

Comment: Jenkins is not meant for TDD, it is a continuous integration engine as well as a kitchen sink... Edited question to be more precise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the package **[ounit](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ounit/ounit.2.0.0/)** enjoys quite a large popularity, there are several other packages like **[kaputt](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/kaputt/kaputt.1.2/)** or **[broken](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/broken/broken.0.4.2/)** – I am the author of the latter.

I guess you are interested as the specific part of TDD where tests can be automated, here is how I do it on my own projects.  You can find a few examples on GitHub such as [Lemonade](https://github.com/michipili/lemonade) or [Rashell](https://github.com/michipili/rashell) that both have a test suite found in their respective `testsuite` folders.

Usually I work according to the according workflow:

1. I start to work simultaneously on tests and interface (`.mli`) files, this way I write a minimal program and do not only write a test case for the functions I want to implement but also have the opportunity to experiment with interfaces to be sure that I have an easy-to-use interface.

For instance, for the interface to the `find(1)` command found in [Rashell_Posix](https://github.com/michipili/rashell/blob/master/src/rashell_Posix.mli#L60) I started by writing [test cases](https://github.com/michipili/rashell/blob/master/testsuite/testPosix.ml#L19):

```
open Broken
open Rashell_Broken
open Rashell_Posix
open Lwt.Infix

let spec base = [
  (true,  0o700, [ base; "a"]);
  (true,  0o750, [ base; "a"; "b"]);
  (false, 0o600, [ base; "a"; "b"; "x"]);
  (false, 0o640, [ base; "a"; "y" ]);
  (true,  0o700, [ base; "c"]);
  (false, 0o200, [ base; "c"; "z"]);
]

let find_fixture =
  let filename = ref "" in
  let cwd = Unix.getcwd () in
  let changeto base =
    filename := base;
    Unix.chdir base;
    Lwt.return base
  in
  let populate base =
    Toolbox.populate (spec base)
  in
  make_fixture
    (fun () ->
       Lwt_main.run
         (Rashell_Mktemp.mktemp ~directory:true ()
          >>= changeto
          >>= populate))
    (fun () ->
       Lwt_main.run
         (Unix.chdir cwd;
          rm ~force:true ~recursive:true [ !filename ]
          |> Lwt_stream.junk_while (fun _ -> true)))

let assert_find id ?expected_failure ?workdir predicate lst =
  assert_equal id ?expected_failure
    ~printer:(fun fft lst -> List.iter (fun x -> Format.fprintf fft " %S" x) lst)
    (fun () -> Lwt_main.run(
         find predicate [ "." ]
         |> Lwt_stream.to_list
         |> Lwt.map (List.filter ((<>) "."))
         |> Lwt.map (List.sort Pervasives.compare)))
    ()
    lst
```

The `spec` and `find_fixture` functions are used to create a file hierarchy with the given names and permissions, to exercise the `find` function. Then the `assert_find` function prepares a test-case comparing the results of a call to `find(1)` with the expected results:

```
  let find_suite =
    make_suite ~fixture:find_fixture "find" "Test suite for find(1)"
    |& assert_find "regular" (Has_kind(S_REG)) [
      "./a/b/x";
      "./a/y";
      "./c/z";
    ]
    |& assert_find "directory" (Has_kind(S_DIR)) [
      "./a";
      "./a/b";
      "./c"
    ]
    |& assert_find "group_can_read" (Has_at_least_permission(0o040)) [
      "./a/b";
      "./a/y"
    ]
    |& assert_find "exact_permission" (Has_exact_permission(0o640)) [
      "./a/y";
    ]
```

Simultaneously I was writing [on the interface file](https://github.com/michipili/rashell/blob/master/src/rashell_Posix.mli#L17):

```
(** The type of file types. *)
type file_kind = Unix.file_kind =
  | S_REG
  | S_DIR
  | S_CHR
  | S_BLK
  | S_LNK
  | S_FIFO
  | S_SOCK

(** File permissions. *)
type file_perm = Unix.file_perm

(** File status *)
type stats = Unix.stats = {
  st_dev: int;
  st_ino: int;
  st_kind: file_kind;
  st_perm: file_perm;
  st_nlink: int;
  st_uid: int;
  st_gid: int;
  st_rdev: int;
  st_size: int;
  st_atime: float;
  st_mtime: float;
  st_ctime: float;
}

type predicate =
  | Prune
  | Has_kind of file_kind
  | Has_suffix of string
  | Is_owned_by_user of int
  | Is_owned_by_group of int
  | Is_newer_than of string
  | Has_exact_permission of int
  | Has_at_least_permission of int
  | Name of string (* Globbing pattern on basename *)
  | And of predicate list
  | Or of predicate list
  | Not of predicate

val find :
  ?workdir:string ->
  ?env:string array ->
  ?follow:bool ->
  ?depthfirst:bool ->
  ?onefilesystem:bool ->
  predicate -> string list -> string Lwt_stream.t
(** [find predicate pathlst] wrapper of the
    {{:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html} find(1)}
    command. *)
```

2. Once I was pleased with my test-cases and interfaces, I could try to compile them, even without an implementation.  This is possible with [bsdowl](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl) by just giving an interface file instead of an implementation file in the [Makefile](https://github.com/michipili/rashell/blob/master/src/Makefile#L19).
   Here compilation probably uncovered a few type errors in my tests that I could fix.
3. When the test compiled against the interface, I could implement the function, starting with an alibi function:

   let find _ =
      failwith "Rashell_Posix.find: Not implemented"

With this implementation I was able to compile my library and my test-suite.  Of-course at this point, the test just fails.

4. At that point, I just needed to implement the `Rashell_Posix.find` function and iterate the tests until they passed.

This is how I do test-driven development in OCaml when I use automated tests.  Some persons see interacting with the REPL as a form of test-driven development, this is a technique that I also like to use, it is rather straightforward to setup and use.  The only setup step to use this latter form of test-driven-development in **Rashell** was to write an `.ocamlinit` file for the toplevel loading all the required libraries.  This file looks like:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "broken";;
#require "lemonade";;
#require "lwt.unix";;
#require "atdgen";;
#directory "/Users/michael/Workshop/rashell/src";;
#directory "/Users/michael/obj/Workshop/rashell/src";;
```

The two `#directory` directives correspond to the directories for sources and objects.

(Disclaimer: if you look carefully at the history, you will find that I took some liberties with the chronology, but there are other projects where I proceed exactly this way – I just cannot remember precisely which ones.)

Comment: you can also do `#require "foo,bar,baz"`

Comment: That's right, but I tend to put these things each on one line to have clean patches. :)